# Shell script to find and delete a text pattern from .java files

Tags: shell

Can anyone help me with a shell script which can do the following?

I want to delete catch block from java files. I need a shell script that can search the catch block and delete it.

I have hundreds of java files which have the following catch block, and they need to be deleted by shell script:

```
} catch (SomeException e) {
if (Loging.isOn()) {
    System.out.println("Exception");
    // and also some code which differs from file to file.
}
```

Comment: *Must* you use a shell script? There are probably better tools for this.

Comment: NO, I have to use shell script, as i have to automatically Checkout - edit - save- checkin the files.. we have the shell script to checkin and checkout... just need the script to edit the files...

Comment: Is this the exact string that you need to delete? You can use find/replace in any text editor then. Some, like edit plus also allow you to do find/replace in multiple files at the same time.

Comment: I believe you're looking for something that can be *called from a shell script*. Which is pretty much anything. You don't need to actually implement your code modification in shell code itself.

Comment: You want to checkin the changes without first reviewing them (much less compiling them)? I would be very reluctant to something like that.

Comment: Amit, I agree with u, but we have shell script to checkin and checkout the files... need to put my code to edit the files in between..

Comment: i just need the shell script which can find and delete the code block in java files, there are 1000's for files., i cannot manually checkout and checkin the files.. :( as Amit said....

Comment: deleting with shell script could destroy your java codes. e.g. your try block has only one catch block, and what happens if a shell script deletes the catch block?

Comment: Kent, we dont have that problem anywhere....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on Windows and have no Linux machine handy. I assume you are on a Linux system. What you need is this sed command, available in BASH on Linux. I have not been able to verify this code, but it should work as written, perhaps with a tweak. This assumes the blocks you want deleted begin with "} catch" and ends with a "}", with no other right curly braces inside that block. Of course, you need to be in the proper directory when you run this code, so use the CD command to get there. If the ” in …” is excluded, the loop will run as if “in $@” was given.

```
for i in /directory/*.java
do
   # echo 'Working on $i file'
   copy $i tempfil.txt
   sed   -e '/\} catch/,/^\}/d' tempfil.txt > $i
done
```